# prove $( \backslash ) \backslash ( \backslash ) =  \backslash $ algebraically

Tags: set-theory

we have to prove $( − ) − ( − ) =  − $ algebraically, where $X,Y$ and $Z$ are sets.

However I am stuck and having trouble getting rid of $Z$, can someone give me some pointers

Comment: You should say in your question what $X, Y, $ and $Z$ are (sets?)

Comment: What does "algebraically" mean in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tag "set-theory" I assume that you are talking about sets here. Assume that $X,Y,Z\subset M$. Then

$$
( \backslash ) \backslash ( \backslash )=( \backslash ) \cap ( \backslash )^c=\\
( \cap ^c) \cap ( \cap ^c)^c=( \cap ^c) \cap (^c \cup )=\\
( \cap ^c \cap ^c) \cup ( \cap ^c\cap ))=X\backslash Y
$$

Answer (score 0):

For sets $A,B,C$ we have $(A\setminus B)\setminus C = A\setminus (B\cup C)$. This follows from a definition chase, or if you are allowed to take complements in a universal set then you can use the identity $A\setminus B = A\cap B^c $ to show
\begin{align*} 
(A\setminus B)\setminus C &= 
(A\cap B^c)\cap C^c \\
&= A\cap (B^c\cap C^c) \\ 
&= A \cap (B\cup C)^c \\ 
&= A\setminus (B\cup C).
\end{align*}
Now put $A=X$, $B=Y$, $C=Y\setminus Z$ and observe that $B\cup C = Y$ to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$A\backslash B = A$ if $A\cap B = \emptyset$. Apply this to $A = X\backslash Y$, $B = Y \backslash Z$.